# azure databricks google bigquery coonectiv8ty error

Tags: azure, google-bigquery, azure-databricks

spark read option for bigquery throws error from Azure databricks

> bigquerystorage.googleapis.com 443 untraceable connect error

Tried to whitelist the above-mentioned bigquerystorage.googleapis.com on network firewall, but still same error.

Any suggestions here?

Comment: check connectivity with `nc -vz bigquerystorage.googleapis.com 443`

Comment: Thanks Alex .I got following output. I am not sure if this means connectivity is fine?  DNS fwd/rev mismatch: bigquerystorage.googleapis.com != fjr02s09-in-f10.1e100.net
bigquerystorage.googleapis.com [172.217.19.170] 443 (https) open

Comment: it's not enough information unfortunately...

Comment: Any other commands/tests do you suggest to run for connectivity check?

Comment: %sh
telnet bigquerystorage.googleapis.com 443

try also other pages to check is connectivity outside work at all